# R: efficient/scalable for calculating column wise stats

Tags: r, dplyr

I need to calculate column-wise stats with following information:

```
  > library(dplyr)
  > Input <- data_frame(id=c(1,2,2,3,3,3),status=c(T,T,T,F,F,F),attri1=c(T,T,F,F,F,F), attri2=c(T,T,T,T,T,F))
  > Input
  Source: local data frame [6 x 4]

       id status attri1 attri2
    (dbl)  (lgl)  (lgl)  (lgl)
  1     1   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE
  2     2   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE
  3     2   TRUE  FALSE   TRUE
  4     3  FALSE  FALSE   TRUE
  5     3  FALSE  FALSE   TRUE
  6     3  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE
```

The output is generated with following procedure. basically, sTaT mean `status ==T` and corresponding attribute is T. sFaT means `status ==F` and `attribute == F`. sFaTuId is based on sFaT and count unique id.

```
  > Output <- data_frame(Attri=names(Input)[c(-1,-2)],sTaT=0,sFaT=0, sTaTuId=0)
  > for (as in Output$Attri){
         sTaT <- Input %>% filter_(as) %>% filter(status) %>% nrow()
         sFaT <- Input %>% filter_(as) %>% filter(!status) %>% nrow()
         sFaTuId <-  Input %>% filter_(as) %>% filter(!status) 
             %>%   select(id) %>% unique() %>% nrow()
         Output[Output$Attri==as,]$sTaT <- sTaT
         Output[Output$Attri==as,]$sFaT <- sFaT
         Output[Output$Attri==as,]$sFaTuId <- sFaTuId
         }

  > Output
  Source: local data frame [2 x 4]

     Attri  sTaT  sFaT sFaTuId
     (chr) (dbl) (dbl)   (dbl)
  1 attri1     2     0       0
  2 attri2     3     2       1
```

However, the process is very slow when there are many rows and attributes columns. Is there an efficient way to calculate this?

Answer (score 1):

We can do this by converting the dataset to 'long' format (`gather`), grouped by 'Attri' and do the `summarise`

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
gather(Input, Attri, Val, attri1:attri2) %>% 
         group_by(Attri) %>% 
         summarise(sTatT = sum(status & Val), 
                   sFaT = sum(!status & Val), 
                   sFaTuId = n_distinct(id[!status & Val]))
# A tibble: 2 × 4
#   Attri sTatT  sFaT sFaTuId
#   <chr> <int> <int>   <int>
#1 attri1     2     0       0
#2 attri2     3     2       1
```

---

Another option is `melt` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
melt(setDT(Input), measure = patterns("^attri\\d+"),
   variable.name = "Attri")[,.(sTatT = sum(status & value),
    sFaT = sum(!status & value), sFaTuId = uniqueN(id[!status & value])) , .(Attri)]
#     Attri sTatT sFaT sFaTuId
#1: attri1     2    0       0
#2: attri2     3    2       1
```

Comment: thanks @akrun for the prompt reply. after running the code, i have following error "Error: Input to n_distinct() must be a single variable name from the data set"

Comment: @HappyCoding  Based on the example, it is working for me using `dplyr_0.5.0`

Comment: @HappyCoding I am not sure whether the behavior of `n_distinct` changed or not.  What is the version of your `dplyr`?  Can you replace `n_distinct` with `uniqueN(id[!status&Val])` from `data.table` or `length(unique(id` from `base R`?

Comment: it was 0.4.3, problem solved after updating the package. also, in original package, n_distinct works individually, but not in the pipeline.

Comment: for attri1:attri2, it can actually spans to attrin, where n is decided at runtime. how to make it more dynamic?

Comment: @HappyCoding  You can use `matches` i.e. `gather(Input, Attri, Val, matches("^attri\\d+"))`

Comment: thanks for the reply. I tried with start_with("attri"), it works with small example. however, as for 25K attributes and 3K rows, R failed and closed unexpectedly. seems this approach doesn't scale well.

Comment: @HappyCoding  Try with `grep` i.e. `gather(Input, Attri, Val, grep("^attri\\d+", names(Input)))`

Comment: @HappyCoding I am not sure if it is the inability of `gather` or not.

Comment: @HappyCoding  Perhaps you can also check the `melt` from `data.table` (updated the post)

Comment: @HappyCoding, Could you please check whether you find the same problem with `melt`?

Comment: tried with melt, has following error: Error in `[.data.table`(melt(setDT(Input), measure = patterns("^attri\\d+"),  : 
  object 'value' not found

Comment: @HappyCoding Which version of `data.table` you have?  I used 1.10.0

Answer (score 0):

I found doparallel would be one of potential solutions.

```
library(doParallel)
no_cores <- detectCores()-1
cl <- makeCluster(no_cores,type = "FORK")
registerDoParallel(cl)
calStats2 <- function (as, id, status){
  tmp <-  (as & status)
  sTaT <- tmp[tmp==TRUE] %>% length()

  tmp <- as & (!status)
  sFaT <- tmp[tmp==TRUE] %>% length()
  sTaTuId <-  id[as&(!status)==TRUE]  %>% unique()  %>% length()
  return(data.frame(c(sTaT,sFaT,sTaTuId)))
}
result <- foreach(i = 3:4, .combine = data.frame) %dopar%  calStats(Input[i], Input$id,Input$status)
names(result) <- names(Input)[c(-1,-2)]
result <- result %>% t()
colnames(result)
colnames(result)<- c("sTaT","sFaT","sTaTuId")
stopCluster(cl)
```